# String field comparison and print the differences

Tags: python

I have tables `A` and `B` and `St_name`, `L_city`, `R_city` columns in both. The requirement is concatenate these three columns on both tables and do a comparison.

Check 1 : If full match then write into a CSV file i.e. :

```
(A.StName + A.L_city + A.RCity) == (B.Stname + B.Lcity + B.RCity)
```

Check 2 : Partial match write into CSV :

```
(A.Stname + A.L_city) == (B.Stname + B.LCity)
```

Check 3 : Partial match write into CSV :

```
(A.Stname + A.R_city) == (B.Stname + B.Rcity)
```

Check 4 : The remaining no match - write to CSV :

I tried creating the field as list and did a comparison. Would you be able to help?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal code example of your two tables (which I assume are pandas DataFrames?)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have two pandas DataFrames:

```
A = pd.DataFrame(...)
B = pd.DataFrame(...)
```

**Check 1** : If full match then write into a CSV file i.e.

```
df = pd.merge(A, B,  how='inner', on=['StName', 'L_city', 'RCity'])
df.to_csv('check1.csv')
```

**Check 2** : Partial match write into CSV

```
df = pd.merge(A, B,  how='inner', on=['StName', 'L_city'])
df.to_csv('check2.csv')
```

**Check 3** : Partial match write into CSV :

```
df = pd.merge(A, B,  how='inner', on=['StName', 'RCity'])
df.to_csv('check3.csv')
```

Read all about pandas Tables merge, join and concatenate [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html).